# Android bundles and messages (some times multiple)

Tags: android, bundle

Still new to android/java and quite confused about bundles, messaging and handlers (apologies if my terminology is not quite correct).  I have a custom dialog class which can display multiple dialogs.  Listeners are set up to pass back data via a handler to the main calling activity.

The data passed back might be one item or many.  In my testing I am attempting to send two items back.  I have tried this a number of ways.  I am always successful in transmitting a single item and having the handler receive it and extract it.  I fail when doing multiple items (in slightly different ways.)

If I put two items into the bundle and send just one message, the handler appears to only receive the 2nd bundle item, not the first.

If I put one item in the bundle, send, clear the bundle and then put the 2nd item in the bundle and send, nothing seems to be received by the handler and the activity hangs.

I have also used the output of msg.toString() and note that if two messeages are sent, the "when" of the second is 0.  Don't know if that matters or not.

Also, I have tried passing message by use of msg.sendToTarget as well as handler.sendMessage(msg) but it does not seem to matter which is used.

Code snips and output here: http://pastebin.com/xtUatEVu

I've left in but commented out some of the other things tried.  I really do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some extensive experimentation I've discovered a few things.  The primary problem was that a message can only be used once, i.e, it is not a reusable envelope which you can put new letters and send again. Additionally, make sure the bundle key is unique.  Note that I also discovered msg.what which is used to store the dialogID.

## The Handler

```
private Handler uiMsgHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i(TAG, "%%%% in the uiMsgHandler");

        // msg.what() contains the dialogID.  The bundle key is the itemID
        if (msg != null) {
            int DlgId = 0;
            int ItemId = 0;

            String value = "";  //leave it to each case to recast the value
            String element = "";

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            Set<String> s = null;

            b = msg.getData();
            Log.i(TAG,"bundle is "+b);

            DlgId = msg.what;
            Log.i(TAG,"DigId is "+DlgId);

            switch (DlgId) {
                case 1:

                    s = b.keySet(); //find the set of keys in this message bundle
                    Log.i(TAG,"s is "+s.toString());
                    Log.i(TAG,"s.size is "+s.size());

                        if (s.size() < 100) {  // we allow up to 100 items, 99 is reserved

                            Iterator itr = s.iterator();
                            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                                element = (String) itr.next();
                                ItemId = Integer.parseInt(element.substring(0,1));
                                value = b.getString(element);
                                Log.i(TAG,"ItemID is "+ItemId+" value is "+value+" itr.next "+itr.hasNext());

                                // now we can handle each specific item

                                switch (ItemId) {
                                    case 1:
                                        Log.i(TAG,"Bundle data for Dialog "+DlgId+" Item "+ItemId+" is "+value);
                                        // do something
                                        // close the dialog
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        Log.i(TAG,"Bundle data for Dialog "+DlgId+" Item "+ItemId+" is "+value);
                                        // do something
                                        // close the dialog
                                        break;
                                    case 99:
                                        Log.i(TAG,"Bundle data for Dialog "+DlgId+" Item "+ItemId+" is "+value);
                                        // Cancel button was pressed
                                        // close the dialog
                                        break;
                                    default: /* item out of range */
                                        Log.i(TAG,"Error ItemID OoR: DialogID "+DlgId+" with message item id "+ItemId+" is out of range");
                                        // close the dialog and toast w/ message
                                        break;
                                } // end of ItemID switch

                            } // end of ItemID iterator while

                        } else { // end of number of items size check
                            Log.i(TAG,"too many items, must be < 100 but is "+s.size());
                        }
                break; // end of case 1

                default: /* dialog id was out of range */
                         Log.i(TAG,"Error: dialog id was out of range");
                         Log.i(TAG,"Bundle data for Dialog "+DlgId+" Item "+ItemId+"is "+value.substring(2));
                        // close the dialog
                        // toast with a message
                break;

            } // end of Dialog switch

        } // msg null check


     }
};
```

=====================================================================

## Portion of the custom dialog

```
                acceptButton = (Button) dialogview.findViewById(r_id_accept);
                rejectButton = (Button) dialogview.findViewById(r_id_reject);

                acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Inform the user the button has been clicked
                        Log.i(TAG, "ACCEPT BUTTON PRESSED");

                        // now we are going to do the messaging
                        // addOptQty is item id 01
                        // addOptPrice is item id 02
                        // msg.what contains the dialogID

                        msg.what=id;
                        b.putString("1",""+addOptQty);
                        b.putString("2",""+addOptPrice);
                        msg.setData(b);

                        // now send the message to the handler
                        try {
                            mResponseHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg,10);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR SENDING MESSAGE");
                        }



                    }
                });

                rejectButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Inform the user the button has been clicked
                        Log.i(TAG,"LOCI BUTTON PRESSED");

                        msg.what=id;
                        b.putString("99","CANCEL");
                        msg.setData(b);

                        // now send the message to the handler
                        try {
                            mResponseHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg,10);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR SENDING MESSAGE");
                        }



                    }
                });
```